# Program creating file path using strdup and strcat crashes when fed more than 39 characters

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to concatenate two char arrays using the function strcat(). However the program crashes.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char *file_path = "D:/MyFolder/YetAnotherFolder/test.txt";
    const char *file_bk_path = strcat(strdup(file_path), ".bk");
    printf("%s\n", file_bk_path);
    return 0;
}
```

The strangest thing to me is that the program indeed produces an output before crashing:

> D:/MyFolder/YetAnotherFolder/test.txt.bk

**What is the reason for this problem and how it can be fixed?**

*Error state is reproduced in Windows (MinGW 7.2.0).*

Comment: Consider what `strdup` actually does to turn the `const char*` into a `char*`. If you were writing `strdup`, how would you write it to support adding arbitrary amounts of data to the end? Would you support that in the first place?

Comment: @chris no, but I would not restrict the size limit to 39 either, that is too small in my opinion. Also, the code works perfectly fine in linux.

Comment: What's the length of the buffer that `strdup` returns? What's the free space it has for concatenating characters?

Comment: And who will call `free` with the string returned by `strdup`?

Comment: Since the question is tagged  C++... Is there any reason why you are not using `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) is creating new memory for you to hold a duplicate of the string. The memory is only as long as `strlen(file_path) + 1`. You then try to add an extra 2 characters into memory that you don't own. You will go out of range of the memory created and create some [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). It might print because setting the memory and printing the first part could be happening correctly, but it is undefined and anything can happen. Also note, in `strdup` you need to call `free` on the memory it creates for you, or you are going to leak some memory.

Here is a much simpler way to do this, use a `std::string`:

```
const char *file_path = "D:/MyFolder/YetAnotherFolder/test.txt";
std::string file_bk_path = std::string(file_path) + ".bk";
std::cout << file_bk_path << "\n";
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/y6B1iP)

If it absolutely needs to be in `C`-style then you are better off controlling the memory yourself:

```
const char *file_path = "D:/MyFolder/YetAnotherFolder/test.txt";
const char *bk_string = ".bk";
char *file_bk_path = malloc((strlen(file_path) + strlen(bk_string) + 1)*sizeof(char));
if (!file_bk_path) { exit(1); }
strcpy(file_bk_path, file_path);
strcat(file_bk_path, bk_string);
printf("%s\n", file_bk_path);
free(file_bk_path);
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/T97RlD)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do strcpy() or strcat() produce any memory leak so that free() is needed?

Comment: @DanielTurizo No, but you need to be careful about there operation, there are no checks on memory or auto resizing. That is why if you are using c++, i would highly recommend using a `std::string` rather then raw memory.

Comment: Thank for the advice. I need the the string to call fopen(), that is why I ended up using a char array.

Comment: @DanielTurizo You should have asked this in the question. Be aware that `std::string` has a member function called `c_str` which will produce what you need for `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and answers, `strdup` mallocs the length of your path string, plus an extra cell for the string end character `'\0'`. When you concatenate to this two characters writing after the allocated area.

Following @Ben's comments, I'd like to elucidate some more:

1. To be clear `strcat` adds a delimiter, but this is already after the memory you were allocated.
2. In general unless you specifically hit no-no addresses, the program will probably run fine - in fact this is a common hard to find bug. If for example you allocate some more memory right after that address, you will be deleting said delimiter (so printing the string will read further into the memory.

So in general, you may be OK crash wise. The crash (probably) occurs when the program ends, and the OS cleans up the memory you forgot to free yourself - That extra cell is a memory leak, and will cause the crash. So you do get a full print, and only after a crash.

Of course all of this is undefined behavior, so may depend on the compiler and OS.

Comment: `strcat` will try to store a brand new delimiter after what it adds.  Either it will crash in the attempt, or the string will end up delimited (although inside the memory space belonging to some other object, or book-keeping data of the memory manager, or whatever)

Comment: @BenVoigt I would say it crashes as soon as it attempts to read `k`, if we try and define it, no?

Comment: Unless the allocation landed directly adjacent to a locked address block, it's likely that both the `strcat` and `printf` run with no apparent difficulty.  The problem may be discovered later, for example when `malloc` is used again (or if the block is freed, but this code leaks instead) or it can go hidden for quite a while, until something else changes and causes a really important piece of data to be stored right where the overflow happens.

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting - So you're saying the crash (probably) happens on program cleanup rather than the illegal read? That actually makes more sense. If this is true I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Probably.  If there were a write to another dynamically allocated object in between the `strcat` and the `printf`, it would be somewhat likely that the terminator would be lost, and then `printf` would happily read onward as you suggest.  And in fact, that could still happen if there is dynamic allocation inside `printf`.  But memory corruption can also lurk in the shadows and strike an innocent piece of code elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @BenVoigt Many thanks, I amended the answer thanks to you.